# Spacing affecting my api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, algolia, hacker-news-api

What's the deal with this one.. 
this gives me the response
https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=Latest&page=0

```
fetchSearchTopStories(searchTerm, page = 0){
      fetch(`${PATH_BASE}${PATH_SEARCH}?${PARAM_SEARCH}${searchTerm}&${PARAM_PAGE}\
${page}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => this.setSearchTopStories(result))
      .catch(e => {

      })
    }
```

but when i do this..
it gives me GET https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=Latest&page=${page} and a No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'  error

```
 fetchSearchTopStories(searchTerm, page = 0){
      fetch(`${PATH_BASE}${PATH_SEARCH}?${PARAM_SEARCH}${searchTerm}&${PARAM_PAGE}\${page}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => this.setSearchTopStories(result))
      .catch(e => {

      })
    }
```

it's the same code.. the second one  ${page} is not in new line the second one gives me the error above.

Comment: It seems that \ before `$` escapes it - can you please try `\\${page}`?

Comment: @eithed same error

Comment: What's the \ _for_? You put it in the code but not in the working (linked) API result.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 fetchSearchTopStories(searchTerm, page = 0){
      fetch(`${PATH_BASE}${PATH_SEARCH}?${PARAM_SEARCH}${searchTerm}&${PARAM_PAGE}`+encodeURIComponent(`\${page}`))
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => this.setSearchTopStories(result))
      .catch(e => {

      })
    }
```

Might be an encoding problem with the backslash.

You can see the URL forms correctly here:
http://jsfiddle.net/e5fqb5vx/6/

Comment: it gives me 404 `Request URL:https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/searchquery=?Latest%26page%3D%24%7Bpage%7D`

Comment: Slightly updated my answer. Why does your server require a backslash in the parameter?